# Chart Type on jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have tested the bar chart code ondocumentation of jqplot site, but It is rendering the line chart on my local machine. Does anyone have any idea why the wrong chart type is being displayed here ?

I have included below java script files in header(as done over jqplot site):

1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery.jqplot.min.js
3. jqplot.pointLabels.min.js
4. jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js
5. jqplot.pointLabels.min.js
6. jqplot.barRenderer.min.js

Source Code : [First Column chart example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)

Find the jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/v2KQA/)

Comment: Where do you see line chart ?

Comment: have you included all required plugins?

Comment: @Tim, I've included all the plugins mentioned on their site( pls. see updated question.)

Comment: @Diode, I am testing the source code on my local machine. On local machine the bar chart code rendering the line chart :(

Comment: Ok. Make a http://jsfiddle.net/. You will get quick answers. Click `Add Resources` in left menu for adding external script files.

Comment: It's wonderful idea, Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/v2KQA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include this dependency:

jqplot.barRenderer.min.js

Comment: Thanks Tim, can you please see my jsfiddle demo.  barRenderer is also included :) It should render column chart. Isn't it? It is rendering line chart.

Comment: for some reason you are missing the "seriesDefaults" part, see  http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/v2KQA/